# Creating a QVideoWidget in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, qtgui, qtmultimedia

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QtWidgets>
#include <QtMultimedia/QCamera>
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaPlayer>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QApplication testQt(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow w;

    QWidget videoContainer(&w);
    w.setCentralWidget(&videoContainer);

    QVideoWidget videoWidget(&videoContainer);

    QCamera cam(&w);
    cam.setViewfinder(&videoWidget);
    cam.start();

    w.show();

    return testQt.exec();
}
```

in which I am trying to create a main window, create a container widget to display video, create a videowidget in that container, and then finally set the viewfinder of the camera to that  videowidget. However, when I try to do this I get the error

> Variable has incomplete type 'QVideoWidget'

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to include the corresponding header as follows:

```
#include <QVideoWidget>
```

You may also need to add this to your project file:

```
QT += multimediawidgets
```

Comment: Sweet! It works. Curious though - If this header needs to be included, then how come it did not previously complain that QVideoWidgets was an undefined symbol or something similar?

Comment: @1110101001: no idea, please provide an SSCCE for introspection.

Comment: @1110101001 QMultmedia headers can find a declaration for the class QVideoWidget, but definitions for this class add only when you added multimediawidgets to the project configuration, multimediawidgets links the project to the class definition and libraries

Comment: In CMake: `find_package(Qt5MultimediaWidgets REQUIRED)` and
`target_link_libraries(... Qt5::MultimediaWidgets)`